# Querying on one-line JSON file through Pyspark

Tags: python, json, pyspark

I've gotton a JSON dump where everything is in only one mega long string. I can import it into my pyspark SQL context with sqlc.read.json(path, multiLine=True).

When i print the schema everything looks fine, however when running df.count() I get only 1 row.

The JSON structure is below, I'm trying to get a dataframe of the data in the 'doc'.

I've tried df.select("rows.doc").show() but this one times out. Maybe I first need to do some flattening?

````
    root
     |-- offset: long (nullable = true)
     |-- rows: array (nullable = true)
     |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
     |    |    |-- doc: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- _id: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- _rev: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- airline_iata_code: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- baseUrl: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- boxId: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- browser: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- category: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- contentId: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- contentIsPremium: boolean (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- contentProvider: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- contentType: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- currentPage: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- elementName: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- event: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- flight_id: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- flight_leg: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- flight_leg_identifier: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- date: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- destination: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- flight_number: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- origin: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- iata: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- isDrmSupported: boolean (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- mac: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- metadata: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- category: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- channel: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- endDate: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- groupId: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- labels: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |-- longDescription: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- eng: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |-- shortDescription: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- eng: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |-- title: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- eng: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- language: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- media: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |-- file: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |-- images: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- default: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- large: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- small: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |-- root: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- mediaType: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- metadata: array (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- $$hashKey: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- label: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- value: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- eng: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- provider: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- sequence: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- startDate: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- supportedLanguages: array (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- tags: array (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- os: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- percentageComplete: long (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- previousPage: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- processed: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- ok: boolean (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- properties: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- browserInfo: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- deviceHeight: long (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- deviceWidth: long (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- language: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- operatingSystem: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- provider: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- selectedLanguage: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- time: long (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- timeOnPageMilliseconds: long (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- timestamp: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- totalTime: long (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- uid: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- userAgent: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- vendor: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- key: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
     |-- total_rows: long (nullable = true)
    ```

df.select("rows.doc").show()

When I use a text editor i'm seeing around 3 million rows for this file, so I would love to get a dataframe with all those rows with the columns; event, timestamp, and _id
````

Comment: `rows.element.doc`?

Comment: This gives me an error "No such struct field element in doc, id, key, value;"

Comment: can you do `spark.read.json(path)`, where spark is an instance of `SparkContext`.